# Facebook sharing not work

Tags: php

**I used the below code for facebook sharing. It is working with google and twitter but not working in fb.Please help me with this code.**

```
<meta property='og:type' content='website' />  
<meta property='og:title' content='<?php echo $title; ?>' />
<meta property='og:locale' content='nl-BE' />  
<meta property='og:url' content='<?php echo ROOT_WWW; ?>' />  
<meta property='og:site_name' content='Immo Margriet' />  
<meta property='og:image' content='<?php echo $met_img; ?>' />
<meta property='og:description' content='<?php echo strip_tags($met_intro); ?>'>
```

**And facebook button as like below.**

http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=&p[summary]=&p[url]=&p[images][0]=','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');"  href="javascript: void(0);" title="Facebook">

Share on Facebook

Comment: try adding this line in your html tag. like  `<html lang="en-US"  
      xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"  
    xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">`.

Comment: I added this but still not show my content in fb

Comment: as said by @Priyadarshni have you tested your page with facebook debug tool.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the URL in Facebook Debug Tool, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/. Scrape your URL again and again and check. It will display the error that you are  missing.

The minimum image size is 200 x 200 pixels. If you try to use an image smaller than this you will see an error in the Sharing Debugger.

Refer the link,

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

Comment: ok. thanks i will check... but always i used image grater than 1000 x 1000 px

Comment: And also inspect the http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php code by clicking F12 to ensure that quotes are properly closed.